# Reading data from SPI on ESP32-WROOM-32

Tags: spi, esp32

I'm newbie with Arduino and need to do a short task: read data from SPI (sent by another microcontroller) and send to WiFi (by ESP32-WROOM-32).

I can't understand how to initialize and read data from SPI. I'm using VSPI. I need to use VSPI class? Or a SPI class?

Any idea will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: can you use uart instead? it's a lot simpler...

Comment: @dandavis unfortunately no

Comment: ESP-32 is not an Arduino

Comment: @Juraj you are correct, but ESP-32 can be programmed with Arduino IDE and arduino code

Comment: do you use the Arduino IDE and the ESP32 Arduino package?

Comment: Yes. WiFi part is running ok. The problem is SPI communication.

Comment: did you see the example of the SPI library?

Comment: I saw SPI_Multiple_Buses example. Is it?

Comment: yes, there is everything explained

Comment: In this example there is no SPI slave. Correct me if I'm wrong. I have a master microcontroller, who send me information on SPI bus. I need do read these information and put on WiFi (ESP-32) connection. In this case ESP-32 is the SPI slave. Right?

Comment: you didn't ask about slave mode. slave can send data to master (if the master requests them). esp32 arduino SPI slave library is not implemented yet